# How to mute accessibility options voice over?

Tags: macos, mac

Sometimes when I double click the power button, I hear a voiceover for accessibility options.

How do I disable this and all other potential voiceovers?

Answer (score 3):

I think everyone is misunderstanding the op. She's not asking about the VoiceOver Accessibility feature, she is asking about the voice over that plays unsolicited when you trigger Accessibility Options by triple clicking the power button. It plays even when you already have VoiceOver turned off. I use triple power to enable/disable colour filters so it's pretty annoying when I'm somewhere quiet (library) and my computer starts speaking.

I figured out a workaround to completely get rid of these types of voice overs:

**System Settings > Accessibility > Vision > Spoken Content > Speaking volume**

Set the slider to the lowest setting. This effectively mutes any spoken content that plays independently of VoiceOver and still allows VoiceOver to work when you turn it on.

Comment: A year late but a generous help indeed

Answer (score 1):

A triple-click on the power button will show the accessibility shortcuts window. In macOS Catalina, you can disable this in System Preferences → Accessibility → Shortcut (at the bottom of the sidebar list) by disabling all the checkboxes in the list. Prior to macOS Catalina it is not possible to disable this action.

Comment: Part of your answer as currently written is only applicable to **macOS Catalina** (and later maybe). The path "System Preferences → Accessibility → Shortcut" doesn't exist in **macOS Mojave** and earlier.

Comment: @user Updated the answer

Comment: RE: "Prior to macOS Catalina it is not possible to disable this action." -- In **macOS Mojave**  and earlier, doesn't unchecking all the checkboxes at **System Preferences** > **Accessibility** > **Gereral** do the same, although not as may options in later **OS** as in "System Preferences → Accessibility → Shortcut" in **macOS Catalina**?

Comment: RE: "Prior to macOS Catalina it is not possible to disable this action." -- In **macOS Mojave** and earlier, doesn't unchecking all the checkboxes at **System Preferences** > **Accessibility** > **Gereral** do the same, although not as may options in later OS as in "System Preferences → Accessibility → Shortcut" in **macOS Catalina**?